# Identify the library

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to learn backbone js from a project that was built by someone else. On the front main application.js file, all I see is commented require statements of the form

```
//= require vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min
//= require vendor/jquery-1.10.2
//= require vendor/date.format
//= require vendor/math
```

However, these are not comments in reality and are import statements of some sort.  Normally a double forward slash in front of a statement in a javascript file makes that line commented. But here, that is not the case for sure as removing any line from the file throws 404 errors in the console. Would someone tell me which library is loading files using this syntax?

Comment: Sprockets: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-directive-processor

Comment: @ elclanrs
The project is built on Node.js and Backbone.js. It is not rails.

Comment: Well, it's something that works the same way, anyway.